# I'm trying to populate a custom cell with an action button

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, ibaction

I'm using a custom cell class to populate a tableview in swift.

I need to get it working for an array of buttons so that each cell has a button that performs an IBAction function unique to that cell.

Here's my cell class declaring the button variable:

```
class taskCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var performTask: UIButton!
    //ignoring code irrelevant to question
}
```

All of my "tasks" that I want to happen when the button is pressed are a variation of the following pattern:

```
@IBAction func task1(sender: AnyObject){
    if (prerequisite1 >= 1 ) {
        prerequisite1 = prerequisite1 - 1;
        points = points + 400;
        prerequisite1Label.text = "\(prerequisite1)";
        pointsLabel.text = "\(points)";
    }
}

@IBAction func task2(sender: AnyObject){
        if (prerequisite2 >= 1 ) {
            prerequisite2 = prerequisite2 - 1;
            points = points + 600;
            prerequisite1Label.text = "\(prerequisite2)";
            pointsLabel.text = "\(points)";
        }
    }
```

Here's my attempt to put them in an array in my viewController that the table is in:

```
let firstTasks:[()->()] = [tasksViewController().task1(), tasksViewController().task2()]
```

And finally here is my attempt at implementing it implementing it in the tableview:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:     NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JobCell
        cell.performTask.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.performTask.addTarget(self, action: firstTasks[indexpath.row], forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)       

        return cell
  }
```

Comment: for this no need to make it complex , jus assign tag in cellforrow method like this : cell.performtask.tag = indexpath.row and then whenver your method invoke you can chek its arguemnt (sender) as sender.tag == yourvalue to make it work

Comment: I'm still stuggling to impliment this. I still can't link performTask to the function tasks

Comment: ping me , now where u got stuck , i will help you out

Comment: Embarrassed to say I don't know what that means...assume it's remotely entering my project?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of keeping the functions array. Why don't you do something like this:

```
class JobCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var performTask: UIButton!
    var actionBlock: (sender: AnyObject?) -> Void?        

    func someFunc() {
       performTask. addTargetself, action: #selector(JobCell.didTapButton(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }

    func didTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {
         actionBlock?(sender)
    }
}
```

In viewController:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",   forIndexPath: indexPath) as! JobCell
    cell.actionBlock = {(sender) in
        // do ur thing
    }
    return cell
}
```